# Guideline for managing multiple dependent projects

Tags: git, project-management

Suppose I have a base project (or framework) which provides features A, B and C. Then I have a second project, which extends the first project and adds feature F to it,  and is used on it's own.

Again, suppose I have a third project which extends the first one and adds feature G to it.

All these three projects can be used separately.

How should one manage this projects in git so that:

- Second and third projects update their own features while getting updates from the first project?
- The code is not duplicated?

For now, I just copy/paste the first project into the second and third project directory (in appropriate place), but this looks so ugly to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git submodules is your way of managing this:

```
http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html
```

Hope this helps. They get some time to get used to. Versioning of libraries that depend on one another are always tricky.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer you question directly, but is there a reason you want to do this on git-level. You can probably keep code bases separated and achieve what you want in other way.

For environments with some form of module/dependency management you can use it to manage dependencies between modules. For example in Java you can use something la Maven to deploy components into repository, then projects can depend on one another, and Maven will manage copying jars where necessary. Similar things can probably be done with Ruby/Gems etc.

For C/C++ and similarly compiled languages, you can probably have some predefined path where you will build lib files and include that libraries while linking.

Comment: To be honest, I had an idea similar to yours. But due to some reasons (time shortage, etc.), I had to go the ugly way. But ultimately, your idea is the way to go.
+1 for the good comment.